# Overriding a method that is not in super

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

I've subclassed `UITextField` in order to show a tool bar with a button when the keyboard is shown.

`UITextField` SubClass:

```
- (void)methodName
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

When the user presses the button and `methodName` is triggered inside the `UITextField`.

I want the same method to be triggered also inside the current ViewController for some more specific code additions relevant only to the current `ViewController`

I thought about getting a referral to the topviewcontroller and trigger my method from inside `methodName` in the `UITextField` subClass but it doesn't feel right.

What's the right way to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the delegation pattern. It may make sense to have your view controller be the delegate of your text field so it is informed when your text field is pressed. 
Something like:

```
textField.delegate = viewController;
```

And have your view controller class implement the appropriate `UITextFieldDelegate` methods so that it is notified when editing begins/ends.

Comment: I don't want to be notified when editing begins. I want to be "notified" when `methodName` is triggered without using NSNotifications.

Comment: Shouldn't make all that much difference. Just create a MyTextFieldDelegate protocol with a method doing whatever you like. Then your methodNameTriggered method in the textField sends the appropriate call to its delegate.